# store multiple strings in one argument python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to store multiple strings in one argument that comes from another method, I'm doing this to assert multiple elements at the same time on my page:

```
def verify_completed_contractor_form(self, arg):
    forms = [
        arg
    ]

    for verify_completed_form in forms:
        self.test_login.assert_element_by_xpath(verify_completed_form)

def test_contractor_form(self):

    self.verify_completed_contractor_form('//h1[contains(.,"Contractor")]',
                                          '// div[text() = "San Diego, CA"]',
                                          '// div[text() = "San Diego"]',
                                          '// div[text() = "Sharam"]')
```

it works if I use more arguments on the first method but I want to avoid creating one argument for every string that I want to find so there's a way to send as many strings as I want using just one argument?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `arg` to `*args`. `args` will be a tuple with all arguments you passed in.So you can call all of these:

```
verify_completed_contractor_form("First")
verify_completed_contractor_form("First","second")
verify_completed_contractor_form("First","second","third")
```

Comment: @user964503 If this answer (or any answer) was helpful, upvote it. If it answered your question, make sure you accept it as the answer.